# Establish a connection P2P without user authentication

Tags: java, android, networking, p2p, prompt

I would like to establish with another user's phone a P2P connection trough my app but I don't want the user prompt window to pop up. Since either I must have my phone rooted or have already connected to that device once,

Is it possible to change the connected devices to my phone and add another one without having connected through my app code?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: *it's not possible*.

The longer one: there is no way you can avoid the `WifiP2p` system prompt being shown. And the fact you cannot disable it unless you have a rooted device is not without a reason. You cannot let some device connect to your phone without notifying you, and without asking your for a consent. It's for the security of the device.